# replitでパッケージをインストールしようとするとエラーが出る

Tags: python

**実行環境:**
Python 3
replit.com

[replit](https://replit.com/) でdiscord.pyを使ったbotを作成しているのですが、パッケージをインストールしようとするとエラーが表示される。

**実行したコマンド:**

```
pip install pycord
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
/home/runner/[repl名]/venv/bin/python3: line 3: exec: : not found
```

#### 試したこと

- 同じ症状に陥っていた人がいないか探した
- インターネットで調べた

Comment: パッケージのインストールするために実行したコマンド等も質問に含めてみてください。 / 利用しているのはオンライン IDE の https://replit.com/ ですか？オンラインサービスなので、通常とは異なる手順になるかもしれません。参考: [Installing packages](https://docs.replit.com/programming-ide/installing-packages)

Comment: pip install pycordとやりました　replit.comで間違いありません

Comment: モジュール名途中の`-`有無で`Discord`のモジュールでは無く`FFMpeg`のラッパーをインストールしているかもしれませんね。[py-cord 2.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/py-cord/), [pycord 0.1.1](https://pypi.org/project/pycord/)

Answer (score 0):

discord.pyならpycordじゃなくて

```
pip install discord.py
```

なのでは？